# How can change the name of a rpm after being installed?

Tags: rpm

I'm install openstack-keystone, it needs python-sqlalchemy >= 0.7.8, but I have already install python-sqlalchemy0.7-0.7.8, can I modify its name?

[root@mycentos home]# /usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install openstack-keystone
Error: Package: python-keystone-2014.1.1-1.el6.noarch (openstack-icehouse)
           Requires: python-sqlalchemy >= 0.7.8
           Available: python-sqlalchemy-0.5.5-3.el6_2.noarch (base)
               python-sqlalchemy = 0.5.5-3.el6_2

[root@mycentos home]# rpm -qi python-sqlalchemy
package python-sqlalchemy is not installed
[root@mycentos home]# rpm -qi python-sqlalchemy0.7
Name        : python-sqlalchemy0.7         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 0.7.8                             Vendor: Fedora Project
Release     : 1.el6                         Build Date: Fri 31 Aug 2012 08:58:17 AM CST
Install Date: Sun 22 Jun 2014 06:10:06 PM CST      Build Host: buildvm-05.phx2.fedoraproject.org
Group       : Development/Libraries         Source RPM: python-sqlalchemy0.7-0.7.8-1.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 12803661                         License: MIT
Signature   : RSA/8, Sat 01 Sep 2012 12:15:55 AM CST, Key ID 3b49df2a0608b895
Packager    : Fedora Project
URL         : http://www.sqlalchemy.org/
Summary     : Modular and flexible ORM library for python

Answer (score 1):

The only way to change the name of a package is to rebuild
the package. There are no alternative ways to change the name.